# Problema con página responsive

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Me encuentro con un problema, no si se si realmente causado por los mediaqueries (ya que lo he comprobado una y otra vez, y con otros proyectos que también tengo y no veo que haya ningún problema.

La cuestión es que he ido haciendo un proyecto, comprovando si el mismo era responsive aumentando y disminuyendo el ancho de la pantalla del navegador, hasta terminarlo, y todo correcto. El problema ha venido que cuando lo he colgado en la nube, cuando lo reviso en mi móvil (entre unos 300px y 450px de width de pantalla) se ve TOTALMENTE diferente a como cuando yo hago la comprobación reduciendo el tamaño de la pantalla manualmente del navegador.

Si os fijáis en la foto, si se comprueba Inspeccionando la pantalla y luego, seleccionando un móvil en concreto para saber como se vería la web en el mismo, el width de la pantalla en ese móvil es de 360px y no me aplica los cambios que debería de verse (con mediaqueries) con esa cantidad de pixeles. Cosa que, quitando esa modalidad y ensanchando/disminuyendo la pantalla manualmente SÍ los aplica.

Agradecería una ayuda. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Comparte ese fragmento de código

Comment: Hay muchas razones por las que esto puede estar pasando, pero la más probable en la que pienso es que usas tamaños Absolutos ( px ) en lugar de tamaños Relativos ( em ) en los textos. Te sugiero leer en w3schools CSSUnits https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba poner lo siguiente en tu head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Se me había olvidado completamente poner eso. MILES DE GRACIAS, de verdad